# Grails asset-pipeline - load assets from jar

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

I'm building an application using grails 3. I use the asset-pipeline plugin to gain access to my js and CSS files (https://github.com/bertramdev/asset-pipeline)

Since I have pretty many assets to load, I would like to use the

```
from '/path/to/file.jar'
```

option described in the documentation to add assets from jar files, but none of the assets from the jar files are found (i guess I get no error message but the asset tags are missing on the page after load).

Assets from

```
grails-app\assets\javascripts
```

are found.

What folder structure of the jar file is required for the assets to be found?

Comment: I believe they are webjars, though never used personally. See info for building on this page - https://www.webjars.org/contributing

Comment: thank you, I'll take a look